# gio operation not supported in a cron task

Tags: gnome, cron, gvfs

I have a task (script) that I added via `crontab -e` (Ubuntu 20.04). The task uses gio to copy a file in /tmp (that was created a line before in the script) to Google Drive. Running the gio command in a shell works fine, but it fails in the task. The failure is

```
gio: file:///tmp/wiki.tar.bz2: Operation not supported
```

Why it it working under the shell but not the task? The task runs under my user (as I can see using `whoami` and `id` in the script and also the file that is created is owned by me)

The script is

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~/
tar jcvf /tmp/wiki.tar.bz2 Wiki
gio copy /tmp/wiki.tar.bz2 google-drive://ittay@company.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://lbolla.info/gio-in-cronjob.html):
Cron runs a restricted environment, so some variables gio need are not present, specifically

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, so in case anyone comes across this issue and is having trouble getting the solution @IttayD suggested to work. It worked for me by adding these to the script with 'export'.

crontab -e

```
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /path/myscript.sh
```

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/USER_ID/bus

<your gio script here...>
```